# Convert stream into Big-decimals

Tags: java, java-stream, bigdecimal

I want to convert stream into `BigDecimal` object. My code:

```
@Named
@Dependent
public class NoteSumOrderValidator implements RosterIntegrityConstraintValidator {

    @Inject
    private MessageBundle bundle;

    @Override
    public List<Notification> validate(Roster roster) {

        Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<RosterRow>>>>>> rost = roster.getRows().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RosterRow::getBeneficiarySurname,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(RosterRow::getBeneficiaryName,
                                Collectors.groupingBy(RosterRow::getBeneficiaryPatronymic,
                                        Collectors.groupingBy(RosterRow::getBeneficiaryIdentificationDocumentSerial,
                                                Collectors.groupingBy(RosterRow::getBeneficiaryIdentificationDocumentNumber)
                                        )))));

        final BigDecimal MAX_ALLOWED = BigDecimal.valueOf(499_999.99);

        rost.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> rost.get(entry.getKey()))
                .map(each -> each.entrySet())
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
                .map(each -> each.entrySet())
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
                .map(each -> each.entrySet())
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
                .map(each -> each.entrySet())
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
                .forEach(group -> {

                    BigDecimal totalAmount = group.stream()
                            .filter(row -> row.getComment().contains("сумма"))
                            .map(RosterRow::getAmount)
                            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

    //                    List<String> objList = new ArrayList();;
    //                    BigDeciaml bd = group.stream().filter(row -> row.getComment())

                    BigDecimal totalAmount1 = group.stream()
                            .filter(row -> row.getComment().contains("сумма"))
                            .map(BigDecimal::new);


                    BigDecimal totalAmount1 = group.stream()
                            .filter(row -> row.getComment().contains("сумма"))
                            .map(BigDecimal::new);
```

It says it is uncompatible .

Comment: Could you post what you have as input and what you want as output?

Comment: What's the type of `group`?

Comment: What is group? What is row? How can row be mapped to BigDecimal?

Comment: You have to specify how to map the type you have (which appears to be a RosterRow) to a BigDecimal.

Comment: Please correct the formatting. And why do you have totalAmount1 twice?

Comment: That’s incredible… note that each of your `.map(each -> each.entrySet()) .flatMap(Collection::stream) .map(entry -> entry.getValue())` steps can be replaced by a simple `.flatMap(each -> each.values().stream())` turning your fifteen operations into five, however, why do you collect into five nested groupings, when all you are going to do afterwards is flat-iterating over the nested elements? You can achieve the same by just applying the final operation to the original stream, skipping all `groupingBy` and `flatMap`ing steps.